# How to get Character Offset X & Y (Coordinates)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I was told about `textRange` in IE, but I can't find equivalent in other browsers for it.
I need a way to read the element's X,Y offsets that the viewer is seeing.

Comment: Could you provide some details as to exactly what you're trying to achieve? Are you talking about getting the coordinates of the user's selection?

Comment: No. I am displaying a text in <a> and I want to know each letter's coordinates on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox has Range object instead of TextRange in IE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range

From the first look I didn't see the methods that return coordinates, but they have something that will come in 4.0 that might help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.getBoundingClientRect

> Returns a ClientRect object that
>   bounds the contents of the range; this
>   a rectangle enclosing the union of the
>   bounding rectangles for all the
>   elements in the range.

You can also look here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aElement.getClientRects

> The returned value is a collection of
>   ClientRect objects, one for each CSS
>   border box associated with the
>   element. Each ClientRect object
>   contains read-only left, top, right
>   and bottom properties describing the
>   border box, in pixels, with the
>   top-left relative to the top-left of
>   the viewport, unless the element is
>   inside an SVG foreignobject element,
>   in which case the top-left is relative
>   to the nearest foreignobject ancestor
>   and in the coordinate system of that
>   foreignobject. For tables with
>   captions, the caption is included even
>   though it's outside the border box of
>   the table.
>
> Originally, Microsoft intended this
>   method to return a TextRectangle
>   object for each line of text. However,
>   the CSSOM working draft specifies that
>   it returns a ClientRect for each
>   border box. For an inline element, the
>   two definitions are the same. But for
>   a block element, Mozilla will return
>   only a single rectangle.

To select:

IE:

```
var range = document.body.createTextRange();
range.moveToElementText(myDiv);
range.select();
```

Firefox, Opera, WebKit nightlies:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(myDiv);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Safari:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.setBaseAndExtent(myDiv, 0, myDiv, 1);
```

Comment: I need FF 3+, is there a way to select inner text?

Comment: It seems that there is no difference between the properties of the letter 'o' & 'F' when selecting each one of them and reading their offsets. is there an explanation of this? I am trying to get coordinates of each letter... (the TOP PIXEL of every letter)

Comment: It probably tells the coordinates of the square that the selection covers and it looks to be the same for all the letters, no matter capital or not. I am not sure you could get the glyph coordinates in the browser, you might be better off using SVG for that if it is possible.

Comment: That last version for Safari is only necessary for really old versions. The second version will work since around Safari 3.0 (not sure exactly).